# syntax error near unexpected token in foreach loop

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have RHEL 5.9 Bash verison 3.2.25(1)
Have following error stack trace:

```
    line 30: syntax error near unexpected token '('
    line 30: 'for i in $( ls "$2"/*.jar );
```

Here is the whole code of sh

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
    echo "Echo Message 1"
    echo "Echo Message 2"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -x "$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java ]; then
    echo "Echo Message 3"
    echo "Echo Message 4"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo Echo Message 5: OK
    exit 1

if [ ! -x "$1" ]; then
    echo Message 6: You supplied $1
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$2" ]; then
    echo Message 7 : OK
    exit 1

if [ ! -x "$2" ]; then
    echo Message 8: You supplied $2 
    exit 1
fi

for i in "$2"/*.jar
do
    CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$i
done

_EXECJAVA = "$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java
CLASSPATH="$JAVA_HOME"/lib/tools.jar

_EXEC="$_EXECJAVA -classpath "$CLASSPATH"
com.example.test.Transaction $3"

$_EXEC
```

Comment: Instead of splitting up your code and asking more than one question for the same code, show us your **whole** code.

Comment: @pfnuesel, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically, your code looks fine. There is probably a different error on a previous line that confuses the `bash` parser, causing it to not expect a command substitution. To help track that down, remove the command substitution with

```
for i in "$2"/*.jar
```

which is the correct way to iterate over a set of file names in any case. You'll still get an error, but perhaps the different error will help you figure out what the real error is some where in lines 1--29.

---

You are missing the closing `fi`s for the `if` statements with Message 5 and 7.

Comment: The line 30 looks fine but the line 31 say the same line 30 had.

Comment: **line 31: 'do**     // What it can be?

Comment: Again, I don't know. The real error is likely in the first 29 lines, which causes the parser to fail on a later line. Please add the entire beginning of the script to your question.

Comment: I've added fi for each statements and result is the same

Comment: Are you sure ?  You must at least have a different error message. I can't reproduce it here because here it runs fine without errors (after adding the two missing "fi"